# css3 background slider, white page flash

Tags: css, background, slider

Im currently using a css3 background slider from codrops:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/

here is the site i have put it on:

http://www.josturdycelebrant.com

what the problem is, is that the client doesn't want the page to flash white or any other colour before the first slider image loads. they just want the image to be there. I've look everywhere and cant seem to find an answer beside making the background the first image in the slider.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this will be a good idea?

A fade-in effect is often used not only for its soft and 'natural' feeling in the rendering but also because it allows the browser a certain amount of time to **completely** load the image, otherwise the user would experience the ugly 'cascading' effect of a loading image. We can quite safely say this will be the case for hi-res images used for backgrounds, as in your example.

Anyways, if you (or your client) still want to give it a try, here's a way to accomplish it.

You need to declare a custom animation optimized for the first image only. Something like:

```
@-webkit-keyframes firstImageAnimation { 
     0% { opacity: 1; }
    17% { opacity: 1; }
    25% { opacity: 0; }
   100% { opacity: 0; } }  /* complete with all other vendor prefixes */
```

Then assign it to the .jpg you want to appear first:

```
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
   background-image:url(path-to-first-image);
   -webkit-animation: firstImageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
      -moz-animation: firstImageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
       -ms-animation: firstImageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
        -o-animation: firstImageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
           animation: firstImageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 

}
```

*(This will override the original animation, still assigned to every other background image).*

This way the first image will promptly pop up right after loading the page. 
Unfortunately after a while you'll notice that this will break the slideshow as that first image will appear all of a sudden right after the very last image fades out.

A simple workaround is to assign the same image as **first** and **last** in the slideshow, with the latter defaulting back to the same animation as any other image except the first.
So in this case it will simply be something like:

```
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(path-to-first-image);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
         -o-animation-delay: 30s;
            animation-delay: 30s;
```

}

This will translate in a seamless transition from the last to the first image in the set.